# What do the recipes do?

Tags: burrito-bison-launcha

Do the recipes that you collect from the end Candy Land do anything?  I can't tell if my luchadors are any more powerful, or if I just know how to make a delicious salsa.  I say that because the recipe I got is a literal recipe: ingredients, instructions, and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct neither the Salsa or the Guacamole do anything to improve the lauchaor these are just end game items we get. Funnily enough both of them are real recipes. :D

Answer (score 1):

After the latest update, as of March 14 2017, the recipes are used for buying items in the ??? store. So please save your recipes now.

Answer (score 1):

The Super Awesome Recetas book is used to acquire another launchador, La Bestia. To get this, of course you will need to get all of the recipe pieces. The launchador is the "Juicy Beast" from the logo of "Juicy Beast".

SPOILER ALERT: La Bestia can do anything the other launchadors can, smash, hook, and fly.